# identifying DNS shortcuts

Tags: dns

I'm working in a private company which has several internal web portals or applications hosted on LAN. So whenever i type "fp/" in the address bar of any browser , it is automatically redirects me to a portal page which is `"http://apps/FPMS/aspx/FPMSHome.aspx"`. Are they using DNS to match the URL for redirecting.? If yes , how can i find other shortcuts like this one.? If no , what is happening behind the screen ? please clarify this :)

Comment: You could use tools like HttpFox to check what's happening. Alternatively, a debugging proxy like Fiddler would also yield that information.

Comment: thanks @DanielB . i tried with HttpFox. When i enter fp/ , the logs shows as redirecting to the link. but i'm eager to know how its getting redirected.

Comment: If these are Windows machines, WINS may be what is used to resolve to IP address.  I see it all the time in well-established organizations especially with file shares.  But the answer below explains how the redirect is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS can't match URLs. It only provides an IP address for a hostname (`fp`, in this case). After acquiring the IP address to connect to, the browser sends its request. This request contains the original hostname – you can see this in the request headers in HttpFox.

For the redirection to work, there has to be a HTTP server listening at the IP address the hostname resolved to. This server is configured to respond to requests containing hostname `fp` with a redirect to `http://apps/FPMS/aspx/FPMSHome.aspx`.

In Apache HTTPd, this would be accomplished like this:

```
<VirtualHost 10.1.2.3:80>
  ServerName fp
  RedirectPermanent / http://apps/FPMS/aspx/FPMSHome.aspx
</VirtualHost>
```

Similar configurations are possible in virtually every HTTP server. Your company most likely uses Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS).